# In Python, how to sum a list of numbers in a tuple, in a list in a dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary, tuples

```
huge =  sum([x for key in G for (_,x) in G[key]]+1)
```

This is what I have so far, though its returning a type error, can only concatenate list (not "int") to list which I don't understand.

Basically Im dealing with a data structure something like

```
{1: [("A",2), ("B",3)]}
```

and so on like that, so that every key in the dictionary has a value which is a list of tuples, and the second item, index = 1 of each tuple are the values I want to sum, so in the example I gave:

```
huge = 5   # i.e. 2 + 3
```

Any advice??

Comment: Recommend you add a line of code that provides the input.

Comment: Looks good, just remove the `+1`. Alternatively: `sum(v[1] for l in G.itervalues() for v in l)`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
>>> G = {1:[("A",2),("B",3)]}
>>> sum(y for v in G.itervalues() for (x, y) in v)
5
```

The errors comes from the expression `[x for key in G for (_,x) in G[key]] + 1` which is trying to add a list and a number. That's a `TypeError`.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're looking for is something like this:

```
for itertools import chain
sum([v for _, v in chain.from_iterable(G.values())])
```

or with lazy evaluation:

```
sum(v for _, v in chain.from_iterable(G.itervalues()))
```

Answer (score 0):

My python's rusty, but you have essentially

```
huge = sum([...list...] + 1)
```

I think it's complaining that you're adding 1 to a list. Did you mean:

```
huge = sum([...list...]) + 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sum = 0
for key, item in data.iteritems():
    for group in item:
        sum += group[-1]
```

Should work just fine.

NOT everything has to be a list comprehension

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the most Pythonic, but it is straight-forward:

```
my_map = {1:[("A",1),("B",2)],2:[("C",3),("D",4)]}

total = 0

for k in my_map.keys():
    this_list = my_map[k]
    for this_tuple in this_list:
        total += this_tuple[1]

print total
```

Comment: Unfortunate variable name choices, ISTM.  This clobbers three builtins: map, list, and tuple.

Comment: Good point. I have edited. The new names aren't great but will serve the example, IMO.

Answer (score 0):

I think we didn't have yet

```
sum(group[1] for value in data.itervalues() for group in value)
```

.

Answer (score 0):

Are you saying you *only* want to sum up the tuples in the list G[1]? If so, this is what you were after:

```
huge = sum(x for _, x in G[1])
```

Note: You don't need to build a new list before summing it; leaving out the square brackets does it in one pass.